# Using switch statements to call functions

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C that uses switch statements to decide which called function to use to convert various values. My instructions were as follows:

"Create a program to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, Celsius to Fahrenheit, inches to centimeter, and centimeters to inches.  Put your choices into a switch statement so they will appear on the screen like below:

```
Select from the menu below to covert temperature or linear menus:



1 Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius

2 Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit

3 Convert Inches to Centimes

4 Convert Centimeters to Inches

5 Exit the program

Enter your selection:
```

ake each of the conversion routines a function that you will call from the main program.  Each of the selections should be a case in a switch statement.  Be sure to comment all your code according to the coding standards.

When I run the program and enter the choice followed by the value to convert, a weird number shows up followed by

```
ProgramExiting.ProgramExiting.
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FahrenheitToCelsiusConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = conversionValue / (9.0 / 5.0) - 32;

    printf("%d", output);
}

void CelsiusToFahrenheitConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = conversionValue * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;

    printf("%d", output);
}

void InchesToCentimetersConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = conversionValue * 2.54;

    printf("%d", output);
}

void CentimetersToInchesConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = conversionValue / 2.54;

    printf("%d", output);
}

int main(void) {

int conversionChoice;
double conversionValue;

printf("Select from the menu below to convert temperature or linear\n");
printf("menus:");
printf("\n");
printf("1 Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius\n");
printf("2 Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit\n");
printf("3 Convert Inches to Centimeters\n");
printf("4 Convert Centimeters to Inches\n");
printf("5 Exit the Program\n");

scanf("%d", &conversionChoice);

printf("Enter the value you wish to convert:\n");
scanf("%d", &conversionValue);

switch (conversionChoice) {

case 1:
    FahrenheitToCelsiusConversion(conversionValue);

case 2:
    CelsiusToFahrenheitConversion(conversionValue);

case 3:
    InchesToCentimetersConversion(conversionValue);

case 4:
    CentimetersToInchesConversion(conversionValue);

case 5:
    printf("Program exiting.");


default:
    printf("Program exiting.");

}

return 0;   

}
```

Comment: C `switch` statements provide automatic *fall-through* unless a `break;` statement is provided in each. For example, you case `1` will execute `1,2,...default` on fall-through.

Comment: I've fixed my switch statement syntax and used proper identifiers for scans in print statements. My issue now is that my outputs are all whole numbers when I want decimals.

Comment: Did you fix all `printf("%d", output);` statements? Which should be `printf("%f", output);` (and I'd probably limit it to a sane `"%.2f"` just to cut down the number of decimal places from the default 5 or 6)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I corrected them to %ld, but was still getting whole numbers. Changed them all to %.2f, but when I tried to convert 5 inches to centimeters, I got 0.00; when I tried to convert 35 fahrenheit to celsius, I somehow got -32. FOr some reason, all multiplication and division is resulting in 0 after changing %ld to %.2f

Comment: Nothing should have ever been `%ld`. `%lf` (on scans and prints) - get that going an then worry about pretty formatting.

Comment: `output = (conversionValue - 32) / (9.0 / 5.0);` for `F->C`, you only need `%f` with `printf` (it will print `double` by default), the critical format specifier is with `scanf` for `conversionValue`, that MUST be `%lf`. Also you only need a single `printf` to print your entire menu -- and -- VALIDATE the **return** of every call to `scanf`.

Comment: "*Centimes*"? Nice! ;-) So you want to also convert "Feet" to "Franc" then, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `break`s for a start. (so if you pick option 1 it will also perform options 2 3 4 and 5)

`conversionValue` is a `double` but you scan it in with `%d`. This means you aren't converting the value you think you are. Basic debug (printing your input values) would highlight that.

All your prints are trying to print a double with `%d` (should be `%lf` for doubles)

Combining output with calculations is bad. i.e. Your `convert` routines should return the converted value and the print should be outside the convert function.

Comment: Which if compiler warnings are properly enable means the compiler is screaming warnings that are being ignored.... (and the mismatch in format specifiers likely is leading to *Undefined Behavior*.)

Comment: @John3136 Thanks for your help. Still new to all this. I hadn't thought to debug, I'm doing that every time now. My issue now is that the program always outputs whole numbers for the results, even though I'm using doubles in everything. What can I change?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow on to your comments, understand that `printf` will print `doubles` using `"%f"` by default, however, to read a `double` with `scanf` you must use the `l` *length-modifier*, e.g. `"%lf"`. A mismatch in format specifiers results in *Undefined Behavior*.

Further, as you found, your `F->C` conversion logic needs... help. The `32` is being subtracted at the wrong point, it should be:

```
void FahrenheitToCelsiusConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = (conversionValue - 32) / (9.0 / 5.0);

    printf ("%.2f\n", output);
}
```

(**note:** the `printf` format change as well)

Further, in `main()` you need only a single call to `printf` (or `fputs` since no conversions are involved) to print the entire menu. When you terminate a line with a double-quote and the next begins with a double-quote, C will concatenate the strings, e.g.

```
    printf ("\nSelect from the menu below to convert temperature or linear\n"
            "menus:\n\n"
            "  1 Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius\n"
            "  2 Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit\n"
            "  3 Convert Inches to Centimeters\n"
            "  4 Convert Centimeters to Inches\n"
            "  5 Exit the Program\n\n"
            "choice: ");
```

Always, always validate all *User Input*, this means at minimum validating the **return** of `scanf` (and if not exiting after a *matching* failure -- you must read and discard all offending characters that remain in `stdin` because when a *matching* failure occurs, no further characters are removed from the input buffer and any offending characters that caused the *matching* failure remain unread just waiting to bite you again on your next attempt to read from the input buffer).

At minimum check that the number of conversions expected completed successfully (and you should further check that any numeric input is within range, if applicable), e.g.

```
     if (scanf ("%d", &conversionChoice) != 1 || conversionChoice < 1 ||
                conversionChoice > 5) {
        fputs ("error: invalid input, or value out of range.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nEnter the value you wish to convert: ");
    if (scanf ("%lf", &conversionValue) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid value input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

You indicate you have added `break` statements to your `switch` statement, but after our discussion of the default *fall-through* behavior, do you understand why the following works?

```
    switch (conversionChoice) {

        case 1:
            FahrenheitToCelsiusConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 2:
            CelsiusToFahrenheitConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 3:
            InchesToCentimetersConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 4:
            CentimetersToInchesConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 5:     /* here you CAN use fall-through */
        default:
            printf("Program exiting.");
            break;
    }
```

Putting all the pieces together, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FahrenheitToCelsiusConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = (conversionValue - 32) / (9.0 / 5.0);

    printf ("%.2f\n", output);
}

void CelsiusToFahrenheitConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = conversionValue * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;

    printf ("%.2f\n", output);
}

void InchesToCentimetersConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = conversionValue * 2.54;

    printf ("%.2f\n", output);
}

void CentimetersToInchesConversion (double conversionValue) {

    double output;

    output = conversionValue / 2.54;

    printf ("%.2f\n", output);
}

int main (void) {

    int conversionChoice;
    double conversionValue;

    printf ("\nSelect from the menu below to convert temperature or linear\n"
            "menus:\n\n"
            "  1 Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius\n"
            "  2 Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit\n"
            "  3 Convert Inches to Centimeters\n"
            "  4 Convert Centimeters to Inches\n"
            "  5 Exit the Program\n\n"
            "choice: ");

    if (scanf ("%d", &conversionChoice) != 1 || conversionChoice < 1 ||
                conversionChoice > 5) {
        fputs ("error: invalid input, or value out of range.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nEnter the value you wish to convert: ");
    if (scanf ("%lf", &conversionValue) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid value input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    switch (conversionChoice) {

        case 1:
            FahrenheitToCelsiusConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 2:
            CelsiusToFahrenheitConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 3:
            InchesToCentimetersConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 4:
            CentimetersToInchesConversion(conversionValue);
            break;
        case 5:     /* here you CAN use fall-through */
        default:
            printf("Program exiting.");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tempconv

Select from the menu below to convert temperature or linear
menus:

  1 Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
  2 Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
  3 Convert Inches to Centimeters
  4 Convert Centimeters to Inches
  5 Exit the Program

choice: 1

Enter the value you wish to convert: 212
100.00
```

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra` to your `gcc` or `clang` compile string. (add `-pedantic` for several additional warnings). For `clang`, instead you can use `-Weverything`. For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windoze), add `/W3` (or use `/Wall` but you will get quite a few extraneous non-code related warnings). Read and understand each warning. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

While not an error, C generally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles. See e.g. [NASA - C Style Guide, 1994](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) As with anything outside the C-Standard, you are bound to find contra-indications, but generally `camelCase` or `MixedCase` are left to java or C++.

If you have any further questions, please just let me know.

Comment: This was super informative. I had already turned in my assignment, but I'll incorporate all this into the version I have locally, so that I can use it for reference. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember C isn't something you learn in a semester, or even a year. It is more a journey of continual learning where you slowly add to your knowledge. The key is to build good practices and habits early, paying close attention to validation of input and initialization of all variables and learn to enable and use your compiler warnings -- they are quite good today compared to 30 years ago.